# Cloud Function - BigQuery returns just an object with domains ( null )

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

The only result that i get is:

> {"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1,"members":[]}}

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');


export default functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {

    var result = queryBigQuery();
    response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));

})


async function queryBigQuery() {
    var bigQuery = new BigQuery({ projectId: 'project-id', keyFilename: "src/credentials-name.json" });

    await bigQuery.query({
        query: 'SELECT * from `project-id.firebase_predictions.com_project_app_ANDROID` LIMIT 10',
        timeoutMs: 10000,
        useLegacySql: false
    }).then( (data) => {
        return data[0];
    }).catch( (error) => {
        return error;
    });

}
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd eliminate variables.  Try running your query as a Node.js function on a Compute Engine or on a local PC.  Validate that your query and credentials are working as desired.  If you get the same error with no Cloud Functions involved then we have removed a major consideration of the questions.

Comment: But in the BigQuery's project i can see the last executed query and there i can find this query with the right credencial's information, so it's woking but is not returning the right data

Comment: Have you tried with this (documentation)[https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/BigQuery]??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the query example here in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/BigQuery#query)?

```
const query = 'SELECT url FROM `publicdata:samples.github_nested` LIMIT 100';     
bigquery.query(query).then(function(data) {
   var rows = data[0];
});
```